# A geometric proof about decagons.

Tags: geometry

Let us have a regular decagon. Prove that the radius of the circle that can be drawn around it (if I have drawn correctly, that's the blue line) equals $|ad|-|ab|$.

[image]

How can I prove this statement, any ideas? :)

Comment: Proposition 10 of Book XIII of Euclid's Elements states that if an equilateral pentagon is inscribed in a circle, then the area of the square on the side of the pentagon equals the sum of the areas of the squares on the sides of the hexagon and the decagon inscribed in the same circle. I wonder if that is related in a way that would help. (But in view of Joffan's answer below, this seems like a simpler proposition than the one in Euclid.)

Comment: So this says $\operatorname{chord}108^\circ-\operatorname{chord}36^\circ=60$ where $\operatorname{chord}$ is [Ptolemy's chord function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy's_table_of_chords), defined by $\operatorname{chord}\theta^\circ={}$length of a chord whose endpoints are separated by an arc of $\theta^\circ$ in a circle of diameter $120$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What software did you use to draw this?

Comment: I found picture on Wikipedia and edited the colors with MS Paint :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Geometrically:

[image]

Angles $ a,b,c $ of triangle

$\begin{align}
a &= (\pi - 3\pi/5)/2 = \pi/5 \\
b & =  2\pi/5\\
\therefore c &= \pi - (a+b) =  2\pi/5\\
\end{align}$

so $\Delta a b c$ is isosceles and so is the similar triangle above, giving the result.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG you can take the radius to be unity. Using the Cosine Law we can easily say that $AD=2\sin\dfrac{3\pi}{10}$ and $AB=2\sin\dfrac{\pi}{10}$ . Then the difference $AD-AB:$

$$2\left(\sin\dfrac{3\pi}{10}-\sin\dfrac{\pi}{10}\right)=4\cos\dfrac{\pi}{5}\sin\dfrac{\pi}{10}={4\cos\dfrac{\pi}{5}\sin\dfrac{\pi}{10}\cos\dfrac{\pi}{10}\over\cos\dfrac{\pi}{10}}$$

$$={2\cos\dfrac{\pi}{5}\sin\dfrac{\pi}{5}\over\cos\dfrac{\pi}{10}}={\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{5}\over \cos\dfrac{\pi}{10}}=1$$
QED

Answer (score 1):

We know that the angle subtended at the centre by $ab$ is $\sin{\pi/5}$ so its length is  $2r\sin{\pi/10}$. Similarly  the length of $ad$ is $2r\sin{3\pi/10}$.

Define $k = \pi/10$, and note that $\sin(x) = \cos(5k-x)$.

Then 
$$\begin{align}|ad|-|ab| &= 2r (\sin{3k}-\sin{k}) \\ 
&= 2r (\sin(2k+k)-\sin(2k-k))\\
&= 2r (2\cos 2k \sin k)\\
&= 2r (\cos 2k \cdot 2\sin k\cos k)/(\cos k)\\
&= r (2\cos 2k \sin 2k)/(\cos k)\\
&= r (\sin 4k)/(\cos k)\\
&= r \\
\square
\end{align}$$